# Create Google Compute Instance with a service account from another Google Project

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, service-accounts

I would like to know whether it is possible to attached a service account created in **my-project-a** to a Google Compute Engine instance in say **my-project-b**?

The following command:

```
gcloud beta compute instances create my-instance \

--service-account=my-service-account@my-project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
--scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform \
--project=my-project-b
```

gives me the following error:

```
(gcloud.beta.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
- The user does not have access to service account 'my-service-account@my-project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  User: 'me@mysite.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account.  me@mysite.com is my account and I'm the owner of the org.
```

Not sure whether this is related, but looking at the UI (in **my-project-b**) there is no option to add a service account from any other projects.  I was hoping to be able to add the account **my-service-account@my-project-a.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could follow these steps to authenticate a service account from my-project-a to an instance in my-project-b:

1. Create a service account in my-project-a with the proper role for compute engine
2. Download the JSON file.
3. Copy the my-project-a new service account email
4. On my-project-b, [add a team member](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members) by using the copied email from the previous step
5. Connect via SSH to your instance in my-project-b
6. Copy the JSON file from the step 2 on your my-project-b instance
7. Run the following command to [activate the service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account):

   gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=YOUR_JSON_FILE
8. Verify by using the following command:

   gcloud auth list

Comment: Thank you @F10, this makes sense. I was however hoping to set this up through the create commandline step.  I will give it a few days before marking this answer as the accepted one.